# SSH can't connect with hostname, works fine with IP

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have a very odd problem with establishing SSH connections..

When I run `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org -v` I hangs at:

```sh
OpenSSH_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/melvinkoopmans/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/melvinkoopmans/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org port 22.
```

It just hangs here indefinitely, it doesn't give an operation time-out or whatever...
I thought that the hostname could not be resolved, however when I run a `dig bitbucket.org` I get a good response:

```sh
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> bitbucket.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31834
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bitbucket.org.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
bitbucket.org.      59  IN  A   18.205.93.1
bitbucket.org.      59  IN  A   18.205.93.0
bitbucket.org.      59  IN  A   18.205.93.2

;; Query time: 38 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 27 12:00:23 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90
```

When using the IP instead of the hostname, `ssh -T git@18.205.93.1 -v`, it works fine!

This occurs for all servers, not just Bitbucket.

Things I've tried so far:

1. DNS settings. Seems to work fine. I use Google's public DNS: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.
2. Stopping DNSMasq.
3. Checked SSH config, nothing special:
   `~/.ssh/config`:

```sh
Host *
    UseKeychain yes
```

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```sh
Host *
   SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

4. `/etc/hosts` file for `bitbucket.org`, nothing.
5. `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

6. Different networks. I tried through Wi-Fi and 4G hotspot of my mobile phone. This didn't solve the problem; looks like network firewall is not the problem then.

System specifications:

- MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave 10.14

Thanks!

Comment: cat /etc/resolv.conf  pls.

Comment: @Istvan See edit.

Comment: Try "ssh -T git@bitbucket.org. -v" See the dot at the end of the name.

Comment: @Istvan Same problem.

Comment: Interesting. When I connect to bitbucket the same way i get the following: debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [18.205.93.0] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.

Comment: I thought you have a DNS problem.

Comment: @Istvan I thought I had a DNS problem as well, it turns out that this problem occurs for all servers, not just Bitbucket...

Comment: Maybe ssh.confing should be also included in the question. If it not not DNS is must be firewall or ssh.config.

Comment: I have my SSH config included already ;) @Istvan

Comment: Can you SSH to other sites? Could be a simple firewall issue.

Comment: @tripleee Nope, this problem occurs on every SSH connection. Not just Bitbucket. Also I tried to connect from different networks, didn't help. I dont have macOS firewall enabled.

Comment: Can you see something suspicious with Wireshark? Both the connection via IP and hostname should make the same packets appear.

Comment: I resolved the issue by recreating the Wi-Fi service.. Not very satisfying, because the actual cause still remains unknown. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem by removing the Wi-Fi service in Network settings, then adding a new fresh Wi-Fi service.

Unfortunately this is not very satisfying, as it still remains unknown what caused the problem..